# Net Core Single File Executable not working

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have gone through the steps in Visual Studio to create a single file executable in Net Core 3.0. The file is successfully created, yet when the .exe file is executed, it briefly flashes in the task bar, but then disappears almost instantly without the window ever flashing on the screen.

It creates a folder located here: %TEMP%\.net\... but the contents of the folder are empty. I have also attached WinDbg, but there is no crash dump created. What might be the problem?

Comment: Can you show the code of the program?

Comment: No, it is about 32k lines of code. I dont think it would help. The program runs fine when it is not a single executable. But not when packaged into the single file.

Comment: Anything in the event log? (EventVwr)

Comment: Ah, yes there is. "Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.ContentLoadException: Could not find ContentTypeReader Type". That will help. Thanks!